# Programmatically setting an image to an image view causing multiple images to show in a table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Here is the problem:

[image]

As you can see, there are multiple pictures showing on top of one another in a table view cell. I would like just the top picture to show. Here is the relevant code that is causing this behavior for the above tableview cell:

```
func cellTwo(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellTwo", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CathyTaskLogTwoTableViewCell

    let pictureImageView = UIImageView()
    pictureImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    pictureImageView.frame.size.width = 100
    pictureImageView.frame.size.height = 100

    cell.pictureMessageTextView.addSubview(pictureImageView)
    pictureImageView.image = pictures[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}
```

So in order to remove the multiple pictures showing I added the following code to the above function:

```
    for subview in cell.pictureMessageTextView.subviews {
        print(cell.pictureMessageTextView.textContainer)
        if subview != pictureImageView {
            if subview != cell.pictureMessageTextView.textContainer {
                subview.removeFromSuperview()
            }

        }
    }
```

However, this causes the multiple picture problem to go away but causes the text to dissapear like so:

[image]

I would like only one picture to show while keeping the text. Anybody have a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that cells are reused. You need to take into account the possibility that you've already given this cell its image view.

When you add the image view, give it a unique `tag`. Prior to that, use `viewWithTag` to determine whether you've already added the image view. If you have, do not add it!

Now you know there is just one image view, and using `viewWithTag` you can get a reference to it. Assign it an image appropriate to this row. Done.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you declare the image view as a property of your cell, and only alloc it when it's nil, thus your reused cells won't have duplicated image views added:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellTwo", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CathyTaskLogTwoTableViewCell

let pictureImageView = cell.pictureImageView
if (!pictureImageView) {
  pictureImageView = UIImageView()
  pictureImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
  pictureImageView.frame.size.width = 100
  pictureImageView.frame.size.height = 100

  cell.pictureImageView = pictureImageView
  cell.pictureMessageTextView.addSubview(pictureImageView)
}
pictureImageView.image = pictures[indexPath.row]

return cell
```